# ticker of title news list suddenly disappears when i use foreach loop in asp.net mvc

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

when i use ticker by foreache loop to list my title of news the ticker disappear
when i use only  li tag static title the ticker works Normally

the error

[image]

when i use  static li

[image]

**Edit**

partial View _breakingnews contains  the foreach

```
 <ul id="ticker01" class="news_sticker">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Take(3))
                {
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/news_thumbnail3.jpg" alt="">@item.Title </a></li>
                }

            </ul>
```

Home controller

```
public PartialViewResult _breakingnews()
    {
        var cat = db.breakingNews.ToList();
        return PartialView(cat);

    }
```

i call partial view in layout

```
        @Html.Action("_breakingnews", "Home")
```

Comment: Please can you create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem - but looks like you don't have enough items in your ticker that doesn't work

Comment: thenk you for feedback i edit my question

Comment: i add more data to table and it works thank you but in last 2 item dissappear  , i want to ask why ticker dosnt work wıth less items ?